# MVC-entering text into textbox with on click event

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have view for entering new entity. On that view I have two buttons: one for saving new entity and another button should enter value into textbox on that form but I can't achieve this, the value in the textbox stays same as it was on page load. Does anyone know how to do this?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. Use javascript
2. Reload the page with additional query string containing the new value

Example with jquery:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" value="old value" />
<input type="button" id="update" value="Update value" />
```

and the script

```
$(function() {
    $('#update').click(function() {
        $('#foo').val('some new value');
    });
});
```